# Split a string in javascript with multiple separators and keep them

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I would like to split a string like that:

```
"'Hi, how are you?' he said."
```

in this array:

```
["'", "Hi", ",", " ", "how", " ", "are", " ", "you", "?", "'", " ", "he", " ", "said", "."]
```

in my js script. I tried with some regexp, but I'm not very good at using it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I'd probably use:

```
"'Hi, how are you?' he said.".match(/\w+|./g);
```

It performs a global match for words (`\w+`) and other characters (`.`) in the given string.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you, I'll accept your answer asap.

Comment: Anyway, I've noticed that with this regex I've lost all the \n characters in my string, any suggestion to keep them?

Comment: @Federinik Just add the `\n` to the other characters group. Can also be done with `/\w+|\W/g`.

Answer (score 2):

```
"'Hi, how are you?' he said.".match(/\w+|\W/g)

//output
["'", "Hi", ",", " ", "how", " ", "are", " ", "you", "?", "'", " ", "he", " ", "said", "."]
```

**Explanation**

`\w+` - For Matching Group of Characters

`\W` - For Matching Non-Character

`|` - `Or` operator between above two (either a Character or a non character)

Comment: The `i` modifier is actuall not necessary since you only use case-independent character classes